# Custom color for each element in Multiselect Streamlit

Tags: python, multi-select, streamlit

Each element has a custom background color. What I want is when you click on an element, the output in the menu bar should give the same color as the element. Now it always gives the element a red color. So it is possible to change the color based on your choice of element. Here is a reproducible example:

```
import streamlit as st

# Styler
st.markdown(
    """
<style>
div[role="listbox"] li:nth-of-type(1){
    background-color: red;
}
div[role="listbox"] li:nth-of-type(2){
    background-color: blue;
}
</style>
""",
    unsafe_allow_html=True,
)

# multiselect
st.multiselect("Options", ["option1", "option2", "option3"])
```

Output open menu:

[image]

Output `option1`:

[image]

Output `option2`:

[image]

As you can see `option2` is again red, but it actually should be blue.

Comment: You want the entire container to be colored or only the selected object field?

Comment: Hi @JamiuShaibu, Only the selected object field. So in this case option 2 should be blue.

Comment: This isnt reproducible anymore. Sadly this behavior is exactly what I wanted. Anybody else looking for how to reproduce this?

Answer (score 2):

I think this should solve your problem

```py
st.markdown("""
<style>
    span[data-baseweb="tag"][role="button"]{
        background-color: blue;
    }
</style>

""", unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

**Edition:**

```py
st.markdown("""
    <style>
        span[data-baseweb="tag"][aria-label="option1, close by backspace"]{
            background-color: blue;
        }
        span[data-baseweb="tag"][aria-label="option2, close by backspace"]{
            background-color: green;
        }
        span[data-baseweb="tag"][aria-label="option3, close by backspace"]{
            background-color: wheat;
        }
    </style>
    """, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Jamiu Shaibu, thank you for your answer. What I actually want is that when you click on in this case "option1" the output should be red and when on "option2" it should be blue and when on "option3" it should be normal. Your answer always returns blue for all options. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Ah ok I if that is the case, I think  a function that can take care of that so I will edit the answer to add a function to that.

Comment: I kinda realized that the function will only work if the multiselect box is based on a select box, so I have to come up with another approach to handle the problem instead of using the function.

Comment: Aah I see. Your third solution is indeed almost there!

Comment: Yeah I think that is the way to get the selected fields colored, you can reposition the colors in the style to your liking. **Note** Incase you rename an object in the multiselect box, you will have to keep track of the item in the style as well because the ***aria-label*** won't be the same.

Comment: Can v achieve this dynamically rather than hard coding the colors for the slected items